# Multiple rewrite rule with different parameters in the same position

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to know if the following would be possible

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$                   /search.php?type=$1&query=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$           /search.php?type=$1&query=$2&condition=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$   /search.php?type=$1&query=$2&page=$3[L]
```

As you can see the first and third row are similiar with the only difference being the name of the third parameter,  the second rule would be used for pages such as

```
/isbn/1203910293/new
```

whilst the third rule would be used for pages such as where page aliases page number

```
/title/harry-potter/2
```

I know this seems quite silly considering I can just call the `condition` parameter, but it would clear things up in the future if used the parameter `page`

Answer (score 0):

The third rule pattern `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$` will *not* match

```
/title/harry-potter/2
```

because the rule requires four parts, e.g.

```
/title/harry-potter/2/xyz
```

or at least a trailing slash

```
/title/harry-potter/2/
```

Instead it will be matched by the second rule pattern, because it has three parts too, just like

```
/isbn/1203910293/new
```

If you want to match page numbers, you need to match against a rule similar to the second rule, but be more specific, like e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d+)$   /search.php?type=$1&query=$2&page=$3 [L]
```